# Vertical centering inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, tags, anchor, center

How can I vertically center the text “Don’t click me”:

`<a href="#" style="background-color:red; display:inline-block; height:100px;">Don’t click me</a>`

https://jsfiddle.net/r1t99rfz/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r1t99rfz/5/ -- I would use tables and centre it, good website to check this on http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

```
.anchor {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Set `line-height` to the same value as `height`